# CSV file on java need to ask user what row to delete, delete it and update table?

Tags: java, file, csv, save, delete-row

Using Java I am trying to delete rows using user input, I want the code to delete the row specified and then update the file.

[image: source screenshot]

I have tried using different methods however there are too many errors in them.

```
B00987  58
B00567  43
B00343  59
B00653  25
B00757  31
B00876  40
B00421  62
B00568  78
B00826  79
B00126  93
B00862  62
B00999  12
B00237  68
B00762  85
B00864  49
B00786  85
```

My Code That is giving me an error:

```
if(!flag)
        pw.printline(line1);
    line1 = br1.readLine();
}
pw.flush();

br1.close();
pw.close();
    {
System.out.println("Student has been deleted sucsessfully");

} catch (Exception e) {


   System.out.println(e.getMessage());


} 
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you tried even if it was not successful/ had errors.

Comment: You need to ask more concrete programming related questions to get answers.

Comment: i have added images of my code

Comment: You need to add the code as text, prune it down to the sections you have questions about and also be more specific what errors you see and what behavior you see and expect

Comment: copy and paste the code into your question

Comment: the variable line1 doesnt exist?

Comment: What Error please?

Comment: The error is <identifier expected>

Comment: You did not define variable `line1` and you defined `flag` multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested But should be enough to go from here:

```
void deleteStudent(String deleteLine)
{
    ....
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.equals(deleteLine))
        {
            pw.printline(line);
        }
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

There are a number of new (streams and NIO2) methods which would make the code more compact, but it requires later Java versions and/or is not beginner level (which can be argued).

Comment: You might need to use a different equals if you don’t specify the whole line to delete but only the student code.